# Cannot Import Python Packages on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, numpy, python-import

I ran this in the terminal to install all the packages for a machine learning project.

`sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose`

It says the packages are already their newest version. When I run `import numpy` from the interpreter prompt, it just runs without a flaw.

But when I say `numpy.version` it says "module 'scipy.version' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/version.pyc'" without showing the version name.  Also, the package import fails when I try a script.

On further experimentation, I figured a script as simple as

```
 # Check python
 print('Hello world')
```

is giving this error from a .py file,

```
    ./Script.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `'Hello world''
./Script.py: line 2: `print('Hello world')'
```

Note that the script and version.version commands run fine from the terminal interpreter prompt.

Is something wrong very deep down?

Python version 2.7.12.

Comment: To read numpy version, use: `numpy.version.version`. As for your other errors, post them in your question.

Comment: Thanks. It works from the terminal interpreter prompt but not from a file. It says Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/print line 528.
Error: no such file "numpy.version.version__"

Answer (score 1):

In order to get to know the version in python,

`import numpy
print numpy.__version__`

numpy.version gives the path.

Comment: Thanks. That works from the interpreter prompt. But not from a script file. It says "Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/print line 528.
Error: no such file "numpy.__version__""

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to check the version of numpy, try this:

`import numpy
numpy.version.version`

2. As for the following question, please post more information.

Comment: Thanks. It works from the terminal interpreter prompt, but not script. Also, for sklearn, what works is sklearn.__version__, but not sklearn.version.version. Also, both of these are different from what was suggested in http://machinelearningmastery.com/?p=2484  I am really confused. Spending more time getting a program to run, than actually understanding the algorithms. :(

Comment: @Della For me, I use **anaconda** to manage my packages like sklearn, numpy, etc. It is more convenient. If you want to check the versions of your packages, type in `conda list` under terminal, you can check all package versions.